How to convert snippets of a word file into HTML in the browser using Mammoth (or another library)?
I have the following snippet of a word document (as XML)
<w:p xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" w14:paraId="5A36C390" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="00B709F1" w:rsidRDefault="00FE05EA" w:rsidP="00056A13">
  <w:pPr>
    <w:keepNext/>
    <w:tabs>
      <w:tab w:val="left" w:pos="1985"/>
    </w:tabs>
    <w:spacing w:after="330" w:line="220" w:lineRule="auto"/>
    <w:jc w:val="center"/>
  </w:pPr>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria" w:hAnsi="Cambria"/>
      <w:b/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>Proof</w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:p>

I want to use Mammoth to convert this snippet into HTML so that I could render it in the browser.
Here's the code that I have.
const encoder = new TextEncoder();
const uint8Array = encoder.encode(snippet); // The snippet is available as a string

const doc = await mammoth.convertToHtml({ arrayBuffer: uint8Array.buffer });

However, I run into the following error when I try to use this code
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Can't find end of central directory : is this a zip file ?

Any suggestions on how I can use mammoth to convert this snippet into an HTML?

just a weak comment: I think mammoth (and other similar libraries like docx4js) are expected to process full docx documents and not just snippets (that's why you got that error.. a docx is actually a zip file containing xml docs). As far as I know there's no something that can easily convert standalone snippets like those you shared... unless you can give some things for granted like counting on a fixed set of elements (like <w:pPr>) and parse them on your own to be converted to plain html

to better develop my thought.. there's actually the possibility to craft a minimal docx on purpose based on that snippet just for the sake of feeding mammoth with a valid document... I made an working demo using jszip but the result is far from what I would expect. The html returned is very basic compared to the wordprocessingml snippet and since I'm not very familiar with this topic I avoided to share the result
